# Experiencing a SyntaxError when trying to select specific rows in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x

I just started to use Python recently. I managed my data via Python. I got a dataset, and I only need the second row and the fourth row and all the rows after the fourth row (and all the columns). My code and example dataset is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataframe with 100 rows
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': range(100), 'B': range(100, 200), 'C': range(200, 300)})

# Use iloc to select the specified rows with all columns
selected_rows = df.iloc[[1, 3:], :]

# Print the selected rows
print(selected_rows)
```

I hope to have a new dataframe like this:

```
     A    B    C
1    1  101  201
3    3  103  203
4    4  104  204
5    5  105  205
6    6  106  206
..  ..  ...  ...
95  95  195  295
96  96  196  296
97  97  197  297
98  98  198  298
99  99  199  299

[98 rows x 3 columns]
```

However, an error popped out as follows:

```
  Input In [3]
    selected_rows = df.iloc[[1, 3:], :]
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seemed to that I can't use `df.iloc[[1, 3:], :]` to select the second row and all the rows after the fourth (including the fourth).

I feel that Python should have the flexibility to select specific row in the middle of the data, and jump to another row and then select all the data after the row. Is there a syntactically-acceptable way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: Interesting question. I am not sure whether pandas can do that with an easy syntax (it is not mentioned on the `iloc` [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)). That said, you can get the dataframe you want with this `selected_rows = df.iloc[np.append(1, np.arange(3, df.shape[0])), :]`